# Finding the center of mass with varying density

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

- Given a triangle $\mathrm{A}\left(2,0\right),\ \mathrm{B}\left(1,3\right),\
  \mathrm{C}\left(5,2\right)\ \mbox{with}\ \rho\left(x,y\right) = x$; I need to find it's centre of mass ?.
- I know I need to integrate the density formula over the region, but I don't understand how to get the limits for the integrals to calculate the area.
- Do I need to find formulas for the lines and somehow use those ?.

Comment: The equations of the line will help: you can express the points in your region using inequalities involving the equations of the lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $\;AB,AC,BC\;$ the respective lines on which the sides $\;AB,AC,BC\;$ lie, thus:

$$\begin{cases}AB:\;y=-3x+6\\{}\\AC:\;y=\cfrac23x-\cfrac43\\{}\\BC:\;y=-\cfrac14x+\cfrac{13}4\end{cases}$$

You should try to do a diagram, and then you need for the mass you need the integrals

$$M=\int_1^2\int_{-3x+6}^{-\frac14x+\frac{13}4} x\,dy\,dx+\int_2^5\int_{\frac23x-\frac43}^{-\frac14x+\frac{13}4}x\,dy\,dx$$

Take it from here.

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble with the integrals, but I think I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes find lines equation is a way to set the correct integral.

Firstly make  a graph of the points and then find the equations you need.

Comment: @DonAntonio has just answered to you!